# Slope or Trend calculation for series or each vector (multiple columns)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

We have multiple time series datasets. Some are by Month, Date and Year.

Here our challenge is scanning the dataset quick and tell the insights to our management instead of creating a dashboard and check by click-click.

Seems like Trend and Slope is interchangeable and experts are computing different way every time. What is the best practice to measure trends or slope?

My data is mostly mixed. I mean some months go up and after up it slightly go down etc. I like to get a number for each vector by that I can compare each vector and tell a story. Thank you so much for your help.

```
## Sample Dataframe
    revenue = [0.85, 0.99, 1.01, 1.12, 1.25, 1.36, 1.28, 1.44]
    expense = [0.5, 0.9, 0.01, 0.12, 0.25, 0.36, 0.28, 0.44]
    net = [0.85, 0.81, 1.01, 1.12, 0.25, 0.36, 0.28, 1.44]
    year = [1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'revenue': revenue,'expense': expense, 'net': net})
```

The result I like to get here is (just sample not exact result :-))..

```
revenue slope/trend: 0.98
expense slope/trend: -0.50
net slope/trend: 0.70
```

Thanks for your help.

---

New Dataset

```
year = [1993, 1994, 1995, 1993, 1994, 1995] 
category =['rev', 'rev', 'exp', 'exp', 'net', 'net'] 
values = [200, 250, 42, 32, 9, 4] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'category': category,'values': values})
```

---

Comment: You may want to look into [Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), which can be implemented in `numpy` or a variety of other libraries.

Comment: I like to have a sample code to solve the problem. I am really new to Python and that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) with `deg=1`, which gives you both **a slope** and **an intercept** in this order. Just take the **first one (slope)** by using a slice `[0]`.

```
import numpy as np

# obtain only the slope part (df below is df1 in your question)
# np.polyfit(x, y, deg) is the order of arguments.
a = np.polyfit(df.year, df.expense, 1)[0]
b = np.polyfit(df.year, df.net, 1)[0]
c = np.polyfit(df.year, df.revenue, 1)[0]

# output
print("slope of expense: {:.3f}, net: {:.3f}, revenue:{:.3f}".format(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
slope of expense: -0.028, net: -0.016, revenue:0.080
```

Hope this helps getting you started with Python :)

---

**EDIT**: To apply above code to your new dataset

```
cats = df1.category.unique().tolist()
slopes = [np.polyfit(df1.loc[df1.category == cat, "year"], df1.loc[df1.category == cat, "values"], 1)[0] for cat in cats]
for cat, slope in zip(cats, slopes):
    print("{} slope/trend: {:.3f}".format(cat, slope))
```

output:

```
rev slope/trend: 50.000
exp slope/trend: 5.000
net slope/trend: -5.000
```

---

Comment: I like your answer. Is there a way I use your code in below dataset? my requirements have slightly changed. Please help. I updated the new dataset in my original question.

Comment: @Murali I edited my answer to adapt to your new dataset. Hopefully this is what you want.

Comment: ...Wonderful solution and it did work on my big dataset. One last request from Python newbie...is there a way I add "intercept, rvalue,pvalue,stderr" etc (other variables) and extract into a dataset or data frame? By that, we can extract the data back to our servers and create a monthly job and track the trends. Again you are wonderful and thank you so much for all your help. Loving Python!!!!

Comment: @Murali I wish I could provide you with a crisp answer here, but I need more context and background about what you are asking for to answer your additional question, so can you post it as a new question? In that way you could get broader helps from the community and also keep each question simpler :-)

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you and I am posting a new question in an hour. Much appreciated.